# Mac OS terminal command "open" throws error -36 when specifying options

Tags: macos, terminal, command

The "open" command works perfectly when I don't give it any options.

Input:

```
Dan$ open mongo.txt
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

If I use the "-e" option, it throws an error.

Input:

```
Dan$ open -e mongo.txt
```

Output:

```
FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/TextEdit.app) failed with error -36.
```

Why does this happen? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Could not reproduce.  Can you give info on your setup?

Comment: I'm not sure what to give. My version is 10.14.5, what else would you like me to send you? Also, how should I get to that info?